IIS Rewrite with angular app and application alas
here is the scenario.
I have an angular app and a .net 8 web api hosting on IIS.  the .net wep api is added to the site as a application with "dotnet" as the alias
I need domain.com/dotnet to pass through but everything else to get rewrite to ./index.html
when I go to
domain.com/dotnet/someRequest the server just redirects to the angualr app instead of giving me the json data from the api.
this is my current IIS rewrite rule
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
             <rules>
                <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern=".*/dotnet/*" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>

Ive also tried this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="DOTNET"  stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*/dotnet/*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="UNENCODED_URL" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Angular Routes"  stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>

if I remove all the rewrite rules then i can get to domain.com/dotnet/getRequest and it will return the json data and i can get to the angualar app by going to domain.com.
HOWEVER if I refresh the page and my url is like domain.com/homepage then IIS cant find the page.
my goal to pass all domain.com/dotnet/* request through and everything else to get rewrite to ./index.html to avoid the refresh issue.
Any help would be greatly apricated!!

I am not experienced with IIS, but if I had to do it using nginx, I would have created another subdomain and used a reverse proxy to host both my webapi and frontend

https://learn.microsoft.com/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/health-diagnostic-performance/troubleshoot-arr-using-frt-rules FRT can reveal what common issues you hit.

You could try this below rule:
 <rewrite>
                <rule name="DotNetPassThrough" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^dotnet/(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="None" /> 
                </rule>

                <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>

OR
 <rewrite>
            <rules>                   
                <rule name="DotNetPassThrough" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="dotnet/(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="None" /> 
                </rule>

              
                <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>

This rule will help you to serve the donet request as it is and will also provide an angular route.

Option one worked for me can you explain what the
'^' means in '^dotnet/(.)'
also why did you add the parenthesis around '.'
thanks for your help!

@Gruneich3 So the '^' means match, from beginning. So, when you set the regular expression in the match url it will always starts from the folder name not from the '/' so I have set '^dotnet/(.)' and not '^/dotnet/(.)' you could also use without parenthesis around. When you set regular expression in condition start from '/' . let me know if anything is still unclear
